# Loop Through JSON file and clear based off dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON file that gets information from users. Over time some of the comments become irrelevant and I am looking for a way to delete the following comments that are older than 3 days and save the JSON File.

JSON:

```
[{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/9/2021 19:37:58 emusk"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/3/2021 10:47:39 bgates"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/9/2021 21:28:5 mzucker"}]
```

Maybe some pseudocode like this:

```
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);
for( let prop in parsedJSON ){
    if (json[parsedJSON] > 3days ){
         json[parsedJSON] = ""
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
const arr=[{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/13/2021 19:37:58 emusk"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/10/2021 10:47:39 bgates"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/11/2021 21:28:5 mzucker"}];
const now=new Date(),d=24*60*60*1000;
const res=arr.filter(c=>(now-new Date(c.EngComment.match(/(?:\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4} (?:\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}/)[0]))/d<3);
console.log(res);
```

Ideally the date should have been kept in a separate property.

But, accepting the fact that it isn't, I go through the elements of the array `arr` with `.filter()`, extract the date from each entry with `match()`, compare it to the current date and time and delete it, if the difference is greater than 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

First off a disclaimers - it would be far better to handle deletion on the server and not in the client.

In the future it would be very helpful to save the data in a object instead of a single string.

Nevertheless let's try to to it anyways:

```js
const dateRegex = /([0-3]?\d\/{1})([01]?\d\/{1})([12]{1}\d{3}\.?)/g;

const data = [{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/13/2021 19:37:58 emusk"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/3/2021 10:47:39 bgates"},
{"EngComment":", <br> <br>2/9/2021 21:28:5 mzucker"}];

// Let's filter the dates and only return the items that is less that 3 days old
const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
  const dateString = item["EngComment"].match(dateRegex);
  
  // Check if we only get one match
  // If a user comments a date then we will get multiple matches - let's skip them
  if (dateString.length === 1) {
    const threeDays = 60*60*24*1000*3
    // Let's formate the string date to an actual date
    const date = new Date(dateString[0]);
    // Lets add the three days and return it in MS as it's easier to work with
    const dateInMs = new Date(date.getTime() + threeDays).getTime()
    
    // Get the current date and check if it's over the item date (+ 3 days)
    if (Date.now() <= dateInMs) {
      return item;
    }
  }
});

// Should return 1 item
console.log(filteredData);
```

Be aware that this has a flaw if a user comments a date, then this solution can't work.
A more solid solution could be to deconstruct the string into an a array of strings we then could work with. But that requires a known structure on how you will save the data, to get the same result for each loop.